# Установка SQL Server Express Edition

Tags: windows-7, sql-server, sql

Привет. При установке SQL Server Express Edition ошибка "Локальный компьютер не входит в отказоустойчевый кластер Windows"

Comment: 2005 или 2008?

Comment: @Nofate, суть вопроса в том, что *ТС* **не туда нажимает**, когда пытается установить **`SQL Express`**, поэтому версия не существенна.

Comment: SQL Server Express Edition 2008

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ставить не Fail over cluster a Stand Alone версию.